# java reflect private variables

Tags: java, reflection

I have some abstract class and some classes that inheritance from it.
I want to make JUNIT tester for it. I tried use reflect on the sub classes but in this way I cant see the private variables in the absract class.
how can I get to, Or maybe I can create instance of the abstract class for this?

Comment: By definition it's impossible to create an instance of an abstract class.

Comment: I understand this. but also their is a way to see private variables.
How can I go into the this abstarct class variables?

Comment: [What's the proper way to test a class with private methods using JUnit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571/whats-the-proper-way-to-test-a-class-with-private-methods-using-junit) explains how to use `setAccessible` which works for fields as well as methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see all fields of a class use Class.getDeclaredFields()

Comment: And to test if the field is private or not, you can use `Field.getModifiers()`.